# getHolder().getSurface() en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy aprendiendo Android , y me he topado con unas líneas de código que no entiendo , si alguien es capaz de explicarmelas estaría agradecido.
Sé que getHolder() viene de SurfaceView , pero no entiendo muy bien.

```
if(getHolder().getSurface().isValid()){
       canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
  }
```

Comment: Y qué es lo que no entiendes? Esto es java. `getHolder()` retorna un objeto al que le ejecutas el método `getSurface()` que retorna otro objeto al que ejecutas el método `isValid()` que retorna un `boolean`. Si es cierto, entra en el `if` y sino, no. Deberías ser más específico con tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo que me refiero es que no sé que hace cada método. GetHolder , getSurface y lockCanvas. He buscado por internet pero no me queda claro